# Returning EDM object without references

Tags: c#, linq, object, asp.net-web-api

I have set up a MVC 4.0 web API in order to serve requests from users that will return information from my database.

I have all the controllers, auth and interfaces etc set up and working, however I am having issues when it comes to returning requested data to the user.

I should note that my functions use and return EDM objects rather than objects that I have created myself as models.

Here is an example function for a user to `GET` a product from the database.

```
public Product Get(int id)
{
        Product product = null;
        try
        {
            using (DataSQLEntities db = new DataSQLEntities())
            {
                product = (from it in db.Products
                               where it.ProductID == id
                               select it).First();                    
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No product with id: {0} could be found", id)),
                ReasonPhrase = "Id not found"
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }
        return product;
}
```

The function works and returns the correct product from the database if I breakpoint before the return, however, when it comes to returning the product through the APIcontroller for serialization (Json or XML, as per the users request) I get a the following error:

`The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection`.

This is due to me employing the use of a `using()` statement in my code, and when the serializer tries to 'get' the value of the fields within the object to be serialized it may need to access the database as the value is a reference to another section of the database. but as the scope of the DB is now gone, it naturally throws this error.

I have looked high and low for a way to prevent the 'Product' object from including any references but there seems to be little to no knowledge out there for this.

I have attempted other changes such as removing the Using statement but I really would rather not do this, and when I do so, it returns far too much data due to foreign keys etc.

I have tried to change the LINQ in an attempt to get around this (see below) but have had no luck, further errors or completely unmanageable code. I would really appreciate any insight or help into how I can avoid returning references within the Product.

**Alternative LINQ:**

**This is totally unmanageable and terrible code but works**

```
var temp = (from it in db.Products
            where it.ProductID == id
            select new
            {
                Name = it.Name,
                Description = it.Description,
                ProductID = it.ProductID
                //Many other fields
            }

return new Product()
           {
               Name = temp.Name,
               Description = temp.Description,
               ProductID = temp.ProductID
               //Many other fields
           }
```

**This didn't work (not that I expected it to)**

```
Product product = null;
//using here
Product temp = (from it in db.Products
            where it.ProductID == id
            select it).First();
product = temp;
//end using
return product
```

If anyone is able to tell me how to get a list of fields for an EDM object such as you would for a normal object using reflection or similar I could possibly write a function to loop the fields nulling references or to minimise the code of the first alternative LINQ code snippet.

Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can detach the entities from your context?

Comment: Could you offer me some links or information where I could look this up in further detail? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: A guess would be something like this `db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Detached;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disabling lazy loading?

```
db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for but it evaded me! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons why you should create view model classes and not expose the domain model directly.

Comment: Yes you're right, but we don't want to have to worry about changes to our database model causing the API to fall out of line e.g adding or removing columns.

Comment: Then you'll suffer the consequences.. This is one of them, but there will be more ;-)

Comment: So you would reccommend creating a model of only everything I want to return in the object and just having to update it manually any time I update the EDM in the rest of the system?

Also out of curiosity what other consequences might this lead to? If you know any off the top of your head? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, the whole idea behind view model is to decouple UI from your domain objects, and return only the relevant data, not the whole grapg of objects. Another problems that might arise are serialization recursion problems, network overhead as you are passing more data than needed, broke apis for external customers if model change, and many many more. Believe me, none wants to write more code for fun, there are good reasons behind the idea of the view model.
BTW, updating view models is trivial with the current refactoring tools available in Visual Studio.